# How to enable "real" symlinks in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, symlink

How can you mount a volume that created real symlinks using command `ln -s` on the host system (Windows 10) as well instead of a file that looks like this:

`XSym
0044
3040baf22a84b530b7df1773a3ab55b6
path/to/target`

Environment ist set up using docker-compose.

Comment: I get the same problem after running yarn install inside a docker container that runs on a windows 10 machine. The same text appears in every file from node_modules/.bin folder.

Comment: I'm seeing this using custom containers in Azure. Seems to affect some files randomly and changes when you restart the container.